# making a RESTful http service for android app and django database?

Tags: android, database, django, http, rest

I am working on a simple android app that needs to access data entries from a database. our server is set up in django and mySQL. From what I understand we need to make a service on the server that will take in the requests from the app in a RESTful manner and send the data back as XML.
So how do I start? Is there a python library?
what about on the app side?

Comment: I have found this for the android app http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/

Answer (score 1):

I've heard good things about [django-piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) for REST APIs, although I haven't tried it. Also, I find JSON much nicer to work with than XML.

Comment: Thanks that looks pretty useful. I would just use httpGet(URI uri) and put etc. in a service on the android side right? Does JSON just convert easier into java objects even though android uses some xml?

Comment: Sorry, I've never worked with android (yet) and haven't used java much. I just find json ant python work well together and json is much easier to read for debugging etc.